# Perl compare date which is defined as string in database

Tags: perl

I think this is a very basic question.
But I have tried various ways and could not figure this out.

I have a string value "21-01-2014". I have to check if this date is greater than Sep-1 2014.

How do I do that?

I used Parse Date.
Eg.

```
if ( ParseDate( $row->{Date} ) >= ParseDate("01-09-2014") ){
}
```

But this did not work.
May be there is a bug here?

Can someone suggest a more simple and straightforward approach.
$row->Date is coming from database and is defined as varchar.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the function `ParseDate` from? Is it defined in a 3rd-party module or in your own code?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about [Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Time-modules-2003.0211/lib/Time/ParseDate.pm), I'll note that it parses dates as `DD/MM/YYYY` **"only if UK, or an invalid mm/dd/yyyy"**. It may be reading the second date as January 9th, US-style.

Comment: The twenty-first day of January in the year 2014 comes _before_ the first day of September in the same year. So your `if` condition _should_ fail.

Answer (score 2):

Where is `ParseDate` coming from? Is it `Time::ParseDate`?

I prefer [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). It has been a standard Perl module since 5.10, and I can specify the format that the date is in. Plus, `Time::Piece` is object oriented:

```
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;

my $time1 = "21-01-2014";
my $time2 = "01-09-2014";   #Assuming this is Sept, 1, 2014

my $time_obj1 = Time::Piece->strptime("$time1", "%d-%m-%Y");
my $time_obj2 = Time::Piece->strptime("$time2", "%d-%m-%Y");

if ( $time_obj1 < $time_obj2 ) {  # Comparing number of days since "the epoc"
    say $time_obj1->dmy . " is older than " . $time_obj2->dmy;
}
else {
    say $time_obj2->dmy . " is older than " . $time_obj1->dmy;
}
```

If you don't want to create *objects*, you can simply use the values returned by `Time::Piece->strptime`:

```
if ( Time::Piece->strptime("$time1", "%d-%m-%Y")
        < Time::Piece->strptime("$time2", "%d-%m-%Y") ) {
    say "$time1 is older than $time2";
}
else {
    say "$time2 is older than $time1";
}
```

The string `%d-%m-%Y` is the format of your date. (And you should check the return value of `Time::Piece->strptime` to make sure you got a valid `Time::Piece` object back. I didn't do that here for simplicity).

You can find the *percent format codes* for dates either in the manpage for [date](http://man.cx/date) or the manpage for [strftime](http://man.cx/strftime).

Comment: W, it worked as expected. I think this is best and most simplest way.